# Create a new list based of .size() result

Tags: jquery, html, list, dom

Using Jquery, I want to create a new list based of the result of .size(); and then have the list item link to coordinating link number

Example is if .size(); returns 4, I want a new list that would be like

```
<ul id="jquery-generated-list">
  <li><a href="#link-to-first-verse">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link-to-second-verse">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link-to-third-verse">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link-to-fourth-verse">Link 4</a></li>
<ul>
```

The reason for this is to create a jump menu for book verses.

```
<ul id="original-list">
  <li>List Item One</li>
  <li>List Item Two</li>
  <li>List Item Three</li>
  <li>List Item Four</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a quick example of where you are trying to do this?  Like an `onclick` event listener or something.  I'm just a little confused on the implementation, and then I can help.

Comment: Also unsure of what exactly you want your list to say. How have you converted <li>List item one</li> to <a href="#link-to-first-verse">Link 1</a>? Where did "link-to-first-verse" come from?

Comment: ok, so I want to do $(document).ready(); and then when the page loads, there is a current list of verses from books. I want to grab the count of that list-items and then create a new list that will act as a table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i, len=/*result of .size()*/;

$('body').append('<ul class="jquery-generated-list"></ul>');

for(i=0;i<len;i++) {

    $('.jquery-generated-list').append('<li></li>');

}
```

This is a quick example showing how to append multiple elements using a loop.  To have custom hrefs, etc., you will need to add those in based on whatever return values you have for your functions.  If you provide more information (including your current implementation of the *.size()* method), I could potentially help you come up with a better solution.